# Prevent \r\n get converted to spaces

Tags: c#, html, escaping

```
htmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P);
htmlTextWriter.WriteEncodedText(text);
htmlTextWriter.RenderEndTag();
```

The `WriteEncodedText` replaces all `\r\n` with spaces. How can I prevent this?

Comment: how can I convert &lt;br&gt; to <br> without using html.decode ?

Answer (score 3):

HTML does not render `\r\n` as you expect. For line breaks, use a `br` tag instead.

Note that, according to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), lines should still end with `\r\n`.

Comment: Note that you can't use `<br>` with `WriteEncodedText` either, as you'll end up with `&lt;br&gt;` in the output.

Comment: @JamesThorpe.. is there any other way?